# How to hide modal window on $route.reload (using angularjs-ui)?

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, angularjs-scope

I have a form in a modal window which adds data to a database. Upon successful addition, I am calling the $route.reload() function to refresh the underlying page, however, my modal window is still shown.

```
$scope.add = function() {
      $http.post('/api/contact', $scope.form).
        success(function(data) {
          $scope.showModal = false;
          $route.reload();
        });
    };
```

The modal is the standard angularjs-ui modal:

```
<div modal="showModal" close="close()" options="opts"> etc </div>
```

I tried to add `$scope.showModal = false;` at the beginning of my controller but that didn't help either.

Here's a code in plnkr:

http://plnkr.co/edit/xz6gJRTBisVCeM0gNLx6?p=preview

Note that I am aware that if you comment out the `$route.reload()` option the items in the list get updated, however in my app I am writing things into a database so I'd need the $route.reload as I need to re-query the DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a timeout before applying the $route.reload() because that's trying to fire off before the browser has time to update the view. This works: http://plnkr.co/edit/E7oraQ?p=preview

Also, unless you're dealing with non-angular stuff, there isn't any reason to reload just to write to the DB. You should be able to re-query within the controller.